# Is using a compact popup or rotary wheel a preferable way to select time in iOS?

Tags: ios

iOS provides 2 ways to perform date selection

### Compact popup

[image]

### Rotary wheel

[image]

---

I found each methods has their own con

### Compact popup

1. Since the popup UI cannot be customized, there is no way to add an Ok/Cancel button. User might be confused on how to confirm after using keypad to input. (For rotary wheel UI, it is possible to embed rotary wheel in an action sheet along with Ok/Cancel button)

### Rotary wheel

1. Slower input speed, as you need to keep "rotate" to reach the desired time.

May I know, what input method is more preferable, to choose among the 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple Human Interface Guidelines (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/pickers/)) seem to recommend using the compact type when space is constrained, i.e. when you can't include the wheel in your UI because there's not enough space for it.

Reading between the lines and maybe more importantly, I would interpret this guidance and the examples shown therein to imply that both the wheel and the compact modal picker are intended to be shown *within your dialog* like you would include other inputs such as text boxes or toggle switches, and not as a stand-alone screen to pick a single time with an option to go back or confirm.